# LLVM pass that measures how much time certain function calls take

Tags: llvm

My idea is to insert a function before the and after those calls, that function measures the time taken and collects the data. I am writing the function in a separate C file following this example https://github.com/sampsyo/llvm-pass-skeleton/tree/rtlib. Here are my questions:

1- Does the external function have to be in C?
2- Are there existing projects that do the same/similar job?
3- Will having LLVM built in or out of source make a difference?

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This is based on my experience developing an instrumentation tool, [Contech](http://bprail.github.io/contech/)).

1. The external function just needs to be able to be linked into the project.  I found it easiest to write instrumentation functions in C, but you may prefer another language.  Do note that other languages may follow different naming / calling conventions.
2. Both Contech and [Harmony](http://arcade.cs.columbia.edu/harmony) have some functionality to do this.  Contech particularly times and records the cost of synchronization functions.
3. I have successfully run Contech both with pre-installed LLVM binaries as well as building it out of source.

The basic idea of the instrumentation would be collecting a start time before making the function call.  After the return, then you can pass along this start time to the follow up instrumentation routine.  Depending on the frequency of these events, the instrumentation may be advised to store the records in a buffer or even pass off the processing to a separate thread.